# Assigning a policy to IAM user to restrict to only one region will access to all services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I want to permit an IAM user to access only single AWS region.(means power user or Admin user for single region).

Tried for EC2 and VPC resources but want to include all other services as well.

Is it possible? can anybody help with this?

Thanks
Kiran

Answer (score 0):

You can try this policy -

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "*",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "aws:RequestedRegion": [
                    "region1",
                    "region2"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to restrict user to user to do all actions in permitted regions only